# Saving data to file - What object should be responsible?

Tags: java, junit, architecture

**Context:**

I am writing a program that identifies test cases that are potentially redundant.

I am using `AspectJ` to trace each test call path and construct a calling context based on this and after the tests are completed I perform analysis on this and produce the results.

Depending on the algorithm and level of calling context needed, will change the time taken for the analysis stage. However, the testing stage is consistent and often takes in excess of 60+ minutes due to the `AspectJ` having to trace every method call.

One method that I identified to get around this was to save the results of the test run, therefore I can simply run my new analysis over this data rather than rerunning. Saving myself time and allowing me to perform tests on larger benchmarks such as `Spring` or `Ant`.

Currently, I am using Ant to batchtest the junits.

I have a service which gets called by the aspect and simply holds all the method calls for each test, this is extracted by an object after completion and then analysed.

**Question:**

Who should be responsible for saving this data to disk? Should it be the object that extracted the data from the service, the service itself or another object that will use the service?

**tldr:**

Should the object holding the data be responsible for saving it?
Or should it be another object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely want the saving to be storage agnostic. I would suggest to have a (separate) abstraction of the storage and then implement it. This way (especially if you want to run different kinds of analysis on the data) you might be able to tweak performance on data persistence and retrieval separate from generating data.

A bit more precise: I would suggest the service called by your aspect should actually use a separate storage service:

```
public interface AnalysisDataStorageService {

      public void save(AnalysisDataObject o); 

      public List<String> getPackageNames(String match);

      public List<String> getClassNames(String match);

      public List<AnalysisDataObject> get(
           String packageNameFilter,
           String classNameFilter,
           int paramterCountFilter,
           Clazz parameterTypeFilter,
           Integer executionTimeOverFilter,
           Integer executionTimeUnderFilter);
 }
```

in this kind of scenario, one class is responsible for generating data, while another one is responsible for saving and retrieving it. Neither one should know or care how the other one actually does it.